# Finding string with multiple condition between two data frame in python

Tags: python, pandas, string, dataframe, data-mining

I have two dataframe `df1` and `df2`.
`df1` has 4 columns.

```
>df1
Neighborhood  Street  Begin Street  End Street
8th Ave       6th St  Church St     Mlk blvd
.....
```

```
>df2
Intersection  Roadway
Mlk blvd      Hue St.
```

I want to add a new column `Count` in `df2` in such a way that for every row in `df2` if any string from `Intersection` or `Roadway` column exists in overall `df1` data frame even once or more, the `count` column will have a value of `1`. For example for this sample dataframe `df2` as `Mlk blvd` is found  in `df1` under `End Street`  column : the `df2` will look like :

```
>df2
Intersection  Roadway   Count
Mlk blvd      Hue St.    1
```

I also wanted to strip the string and make it case neutral to match it. However, I am not sure how would I set this matching logic using `.iloc` . How could I solve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Flatten the values in `df1` and `map` to lower case, then convert the values in `df2` to lower case and use `isin` + `any` to test for the match

```
vals = map(str.lower, df1.values.ravel())
df2['count'] = df2.applymap(str.lower).isin(vals).any(1).astype(int)
```

---

```
  Intersection  Roadway  count
0     Mlk blvd  Hue St.      1
```